# Creating a list of slices of another list by getting elements between given indexes

Tags: python, nested-lists

I am analysing an output from a serial sniffer and I want to count number of bytes in between following timestamps. I have turned my log into a list of strings `lines` and it looks somehow like this:

> timestamp (index 0)
>
> data (index 1)
>
> data (index 2)
>
> and so on
>
> timestamp (index 215)
>
> data (index 216)
>
> and so on...

So I want to create a nested list `messages` that for example, it's first element `messages[0]` will be elements of `lines` from index 1 to index 214.

I have created a list `timeindexes` of indexes of timestamps and a separate list `nospaces` where I got rid of spaces between characters in elements between timestamps- when counting bytes I will just divide the number of characters by 2.

```
f=open("snnifflog.txt","r")
lines=[l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
lines_number=len(lines)

l=0
timeindex=[]
# list of indexes of timestamps in my lines list
while l<lines_number:
    if lines[l].startswith("2019"):
        timeindex.append(l)
    l+=1

nospaces=[]
n=0
#lines list modified by getting rid of spaces
while n<lines_number:
    if not lines[n].startswith("2019"):
        nospaces.append(lines[n].replace(" ",""))
    else:
        nospaces.append(lines[n])
    n+=1
```

And now I don't know how to append my list. I understand that it's rows should be indexed from 0 to `len(timeindex)-2` and they should be lists composed of elements:

zero row:

`nospaces[timeindex[0]+1]` till `nospaces[timeindex[1]-1]`

then row 1:

`nospaces[timeindex[1]+1]` till `nospaces[timeindex[2]-1]`

and so on...

I don't know how to write a loop for this

Answer (score 0):

Here is **exactly** what you described in you question and I have no idea what are you doing and why you need this.

```
with open("snnifflog.txt") as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

timeindex = [i for i in range(len(lines)) if lines[i].startswith("2019")]
nospaces = [s.replace(" ", "") if i not in timeindex else s for i, s in enumerate(lines)]
messages = [nospaces[timeindex[i] + 1: timeindex[i + 1]] for i in range(len(timeindex) - 2)]
```